# Images in Browser are broken

Tags: python, html, django

Images in the browser are broken.
Using Google's inspect element tool,
I found my images sources are like
`<img class="img" src="/image/images/images/xxx.jpeg">`

In my app, images are in the `image(child app)/images/` directory.
So, I deleted images from src and changed into `src="/image/images/xxx.jpeg"`, but the images are still broken.

I tried to write full path of images in the address bar in Chrome (it is like
`file://Users/Desktop/AppName/image/images/xxx.jpeg`), but a browser error occurred. I wrote full path of images in search box and I designate　images in my computers (it is like `file://yname/Desktop/xxx.jpeg`), then the images were shown in browser.

So, I really cannot understand how to fix it.

In `views.py`, I wrote

```
def upload_save(request):

    photo_id = request.POST.get("p_id", "")

    if (photo_id):
        photo_obj = Post.objects.get(id=photo_id)
    else:
        photo_obj = Post()

    files = request.FILES.getlist("files[]")

    photo_obj.image = files[0]

    photo_obj.save()

    photos = Post.objects.all()
    context = {
        'photos': photos,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/photo.html', context)
```

In photo.html,

```
{% extends "registration/accounts/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  {% for photo in photos %}
    <h2 class="page-header">{{ photos.title }}</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="/image/images/{{ photo.image }}">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'accounts:upload' photo.id %}">UPLOAD</a>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

What should I do?

Comment: How did you setup the [static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial06/)?

Comment: Why are you serving images via `file://`?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading the static file section of the official documentation

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

In your settings.py file you will probably have to set

```
STATIC_URL = '/image/'
```

Then in your templates you have to change image source to use your static files pointer:

```
{% load staticfiles %} #put this at the top

<img src="{% static "images/{{photo.image}}" %}"
```

Check in the browser what the image source is resolved to. It should be something like localhost/your_app_name/image/images/image_name

Edit: Also check if the images are really in the directory you think they should be.